# Show PageNumbers in PDF using iText 1.3.1

Tags: itext

I am trying to add the Pagenumbers in PDF document, have gone through few posts but those all were more or less with latest version of iText.
Our problem is that we want to get this working with iText version 1.3.1 only.
Please suggest the valuable inputs for the same.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are using a version of iText that was released on May 9, 2005, almost 14 years ago. That version is no longer supported by iText Software. We can help you to upgrade to iText 7.

Comment: I'm curious about the "1.3.1 only" requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are the problems? Show us some code - ideally an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve